# I'm trying to create a macro which copies and pastes a range together with the objects in the range at a new variable location

Tags: excel, vba, object, radio-button

My intent is to copy a range together with the objects(radio button) and paste it at an dynamic location (at an offset of 15 columns) then update all the cell references of the newly pasted objects relative to their position. i.e. if location of radio button (object) = "AF22" then linked cell = 1st column of new range + 11 columns to the right (e.g. Column T + 11 columns = Column "AD") hence new cell reference = "AD22"
**EDIT: I've removed a part of my code which seemed redundant. The below code perfectly copies and pastes the data and objects. However I need help in the Linkedcell part**

```
`Sub Macro2()
Dim rng, rng1, rng2 As Range, s As Shape, ws As Worksheet, sr As 
ShapeRange, Loc As String
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("E19")
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("T19:AF34")
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("E19:Q34")

'Copy the range with text and paste it to the desired location

ActiveSheet.Range("E19:Q34").copy

With rng
rng.Offset(0, 15).Select
ws.Paste
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End With

'Trying to find option buttons and give them a new cell reference.(linked cell)
 With ActiveSheet
    'Selection = Range("V19:AC34")
    For Each s In .Shapes
        'if s.TopLeftCell.Column =
         '   .Range ("V19:AC34")

    If s.Name Like "OptionButton*" Then

     s.DrawingObject.LinkedCell = "=" & Chr(s.TopLeftCell.Column) & CStr(s.TopLeftCell.Row)
     Debug.Print s.DrawingObject.LinkedCell

        'Loc = "AD" & s.TopLeftCell.Row
        'Debug.Print Loc
        '.Value = xlOff
        'Selection.LinkedCell = Range(Loc).Address
        '.Display3DShading = False
        End If
 'End With
    Next s
 End With



End Sub`
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Object doesnt support this propert or method error" on the line:        For Each s In rng2.Shapes

Comment: There is no `Shapes` property for a range!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @FaneDuru. Is there a way I could choose all the Shapes/objects within a range then?

Comment: Yes, it is... I will post an answer...

Comment: @FaneDuru, my code has 3 types of objects, - Check box, Group box and Option button (radio button). However, only option button requires linking to the respective row.

Comment: Your intention is wrong because shapes are on a separate pane from cells. They can't be "copied together". Copy your cells in the normal way. References in the affected formulas should adjust automatically. Then loop through your radio buttons and move them - a process not covered by your present question. If they are linked to certain cells in the worksheet these references should adjust automatically in the copying process. If they don't, reset them in the loop that moves them (You might use the `LinkedCell` property to identify which buttons to move).

Comment: Hi @Variatus, thanks for your reply. My code does copy and pastes all the data together with the objects in the new location . I thought the optionbuttons would behave the same way as you said. but unfortunately they seem not to be changing their reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code to select/copy a shape of a range selection:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape, rng As Range, optB As OLEObject
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = sh.Range("your range containing the Option Button to be copied")
    With ws 
      For Each s In .Shapes
        If Not Intersect(Range(s.TopLeftCell.Address), Range(rng.Address)) Is Nothing Then
            If s.Name = "OptionButton1" Then 'use here your option button name
                s.Copy
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
      Next s
    End With
    rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 15).Select
    ws.Paste
    'Generic way of identifying the newly pasted Option button and allocate a `LinkedCell` to it:
    'Set optB = ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count).OLEFormat.Object
    'optB.LinkedCell = "=" & rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 15).Address
    Selection.LinkedCell = rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 15).Address
```

A trick must be used in order to do that, but using the `ActiveSheet.Shapes`...
Using of `rng.Cells.Offset(0, 15).Select` is not wise. This will select so many cells as the range has. I have chosen to paste it referring the first cell of the range.  If you want/need a different position, it will be easy to adapt the code (`rng.Cells()`), I think.

Edited: I adapted the code to select and copy only a shape named "OptionButton1". Please, take care to use here your real shape name!

I also showed a way to allocate a `LinkedCell` to the newly created Option Button. I must confess that, looking to your code, I did not understand what cell you tried to link. I used a generic one, the same used for moving the shape. Please use here an appropriate address, according to your  need.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209709/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-im-trying-to-create-a-macro-which-copies-and-p).